# python exception from module is not caught

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to catch an exception from vk_api module. I imported it:

```
import vk_api
```

then wrote some code, and then i screwed up my token on purpose so i can check if exception catch works:

```
try:
    vk.method('wall.post', params)
except vk_api.exceptions.ApiError:
    print('caught')
```

but it still gives me an error:

```
vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [5] User authorization failed: invalid access_token (4).
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Try "except ApiError:" ?

Comment: The error comes probably from somewhere else in your code. Please provide a wider code sample. Or you can try `exept Exception as err` then `print(type(err))` to make sure you have the right type for the exception you try to catch.

Comment: You should also check how is named the `vk_api` module in your namespace. You call `vk.method(...)` (`vk` in the namespace) and try to catch `vk_api.exception...` (`vk_api` in the namespace).

Comment: @ValentinM. Alright, as you wrote, error was from other part of code which i didn't realize initially. I tried to catch an exception in the final part of the script where it submitted the post to server, _but error was raised when the token was first used in code_ and that's where i needed to place 'try' block. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error comes from somewhere else in your code. You can have a better idea of where it comes from by using a wider `try/except` block.

Answer (score -1):

```
try:
    vk_session.auth(token_only=True)
except vk_api.AuthError as error_msg:
    print(error_msg)
    return
```

You can check it out an example [here](https://github.com/python273/vk_api/blob/master/examples/longpoll.py).

It seems the correct usage is `vk_api.[ErrorName]`

Your answer is

```
try:
    vk.method('wall.post', params)
except vk_api.ApiError:
    print('caught')
```